# SP2013 Fails to create Publishing Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-site, access-denied

My client can no longer create Publishing Site Collections.  Problem started in June 2017 (around the time they patched with June 2017CU).  Here are the specifics:

- can create a Publishing site using PowerShell, but in the UI, it fails with this screen:

[image]

- Lots of info in the log file:

  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetProperties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPropertyBag..ctor(GetProperties getProperties, UpdateProperties updateProperties)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Properties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.GetLookupListId(SPSite site)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.Initialize(SPFieldCollection fields)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField..ctor(SPFieldCollection fields, String typeName, String displayName)

  Feature receiver assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c', class 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFeatureReceiver', method 'FeatureActivated' for feature '73ef14b1-13a9-416b-a9b5-ececa2b0604c' threw an exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebMetainfo(String bstrUrl)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetProperties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPropertyBag..ctor(GetProperties getProperties, UpdateProperties updateProperties)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Properties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.GetLookupListId(SPSite site)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()

  Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'TaxonomyFieldAdded' (ID: '73ef14b1-13a9-416b-a9b5-ececa2b0604c').  Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebMetainfo(String bstrUrl)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetProperties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPropertyBag..ctor(GetProperties getProperties, UpdateProperties updateProperties)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Properties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.GetLookupListId(SPSite site)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a()

  Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'Navigation' (ID: '89e0306d-453b-4ec5-8d68-42067cdbf98e').  Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebMetainfo(String bstrUrl)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetProperties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPropertyBag..ctor(GetProperties getProperties, UpdateProperties updateProperties)
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Properties()
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.GetLookupListId(SPSite site)

  Failed to activate site features when provisioning site at url "https://vvvv.zzzz.com/sites/sptest04" with site definition "BLANKINTERNET#0".

  - AccessDenied is all throughout these log errors.  I am running this as an Admin in Farm Administrators group.
  - Fails trying to activate TaxonomyFieldAdded Feature (hidden)
  - I can create a Publishing sub-site in an existing Site Collection without issue
  - ManagedMetadata Service is running and appears normal
  - Server is patched through the November 2017 CU
  - There are no custom Solutions/Features added

What are some thoughts on this? What else can I supply to assist?

Comment: Can you make sure the user that runs the powershell command to create a publishing site is same as the one who creates it on the UI?

Comment: Yes, they are both the same user.  The user is a Farm Admin.

Comment: One thing I noticed, when I run CA, I have to explicitly "Run As Administrator".  I am testing again now to ensure the same account gets 2 different results.

Comment: Verified that the same account fails while trying to create the site in the UI, but succeeds using PowerShell, same as always.

Comment: Can you try creating a site collection with `Team Site` template on the UI and then activate the `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` site collection feature?

Answer (score 0):

From log i can see you are using "BLANKINTERNET#0" , but Publishing portal is map to "BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER#0" .

You can verify this from the site creation page by using your browser's dev tools and looking at the select option that represents the site you're trying to create:

[image]

This is the difference between create publishing site collection using PowerShell and CA . let's say publishing site is different with publishing portal .

More information refer to : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2010/10/21/sharepoint-templates-and-their-ids/ .

Comment: Yes, when I select Publishing Portal, it shows exactly what you have shown above.  It is OOTB SharePoint code that is using the reference to "BLANKINTERNET#0" above.